# Is a Password secure if I change one letter?

Tags: passwords, veracrypt

If I use a long password (64 characters), which is written on paper and its encrypted content never sees the internet (veracrypt volume), would a secondary volume with the same password, but one letter changed

a) compromise the password itself?

b) compromise the encrypted content?

Answer (score 2):

Unless the attacker managed to get access to one password (which would obviously make it much easier to guess the other one), the answer is no.

Veracrypt will hash your password with the hash function you selected when creating the volume, and that function will make sure that a slight deviation in the input (your 64 character password), will have an unpredictable output. The result of that hash is what is used to encrypt the master key.

Comment: The effective key being used to encrypt/decrypt the master key (the "key encryption key") will be quite different, **but** any attacker having found out one password, might assume that the other password uses a similar pattern. It may take some time to find out, but it will be significantly faster than trying without any knowledge about the password.